# JRadioButtons in a custom JScrollPane not appearing?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jradiobutton, buttongroup

I'm writing an IM client GUI for a project.  On the left of the window, I want a scrolling pane that has radio buttons for each active user, so that when a New Chat button is pushed, a chat will be created with the selected user.

I've implemented a sample GUI with 3 given users.  I create a JRadioButton for each, set an ActionCommand and an ActionListener, add it to the ButtonGroup and then add it to 'this', which is a class extending JScrollPane.  However, when I run the code, I see only an empty frame on the left hand side, with no buttons present.  Can anybody explain?  Relevant code is below.

```
package gui;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ActiveList extends JScrollPane implements ActionListener {
    private ButtonGroup group;
    private String selected;

    public ActiveList() {
        //TODO: will eventually need access to Server's list of active usernames
        String[] usernames = {"User1", "User2", "User3"};
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        this.group = group;

        for (String name: usernames) {
            JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton(name);
            button.setActionCommand(name);
            button.addActionListener(this);
            this.group.add(button);
            this.add(button);
        }
    }

    public String getSelected() {
        return this.selected;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.selected = e.getActionCommand(); 
        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
    }

}
```

The main method that I'm running comes from another class, ChatGUI.java.  The ConversationsPane container is another class in my GUI, which is working correctly.

```
package gui;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChatGUI extends JFrame {
    private ConversationsPane convos;
    private ActiveList users;

    public ChatGUI() {
        ConversationsPane convos = new ConversationsPane();
        this.convos = convos;
        ActiveList users = new ActiveList();
        this.users = users;

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this.getContentPane()); 
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(users, 100, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(convos)
         );

        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(users)
                .addComponent(convos)
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChatGUI ui = new ChatGUI();
        ui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ui.setVisible(true);
        ui.setSize(800,400);
        ui.convos.newChat("Chat A");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd be use JList with Icon instead of JRadioButton, then ListSelectionListner can to react to selections event in the JList

Comment: What is a `ConversationsPane`?  Answer in the form of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how scroll panes work.  You do not "add" components to them.  You set **A** component to the scroll panes view port

[image]

Instead of extending `JScrollPane`, as you are adding no value to it, try doing something more like...

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
JPanel view = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
String[] usernames = {"User1", "User2", "User3"};
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
this.group = group;

for (String name: usernames) {
    JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton(name);
    button.setActionCommand(name);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    this.group.add(button);
    view.add(button);
}

scrollPane.setViewportView(view);
// Add scrollpane to WEST position of main view
```

Instead...

Take a look at [How to use scroll panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details...

Comment: This makes sense!  I'd seen that link googling my problem before posting, but wasn't able to understand much from it, but the way you wrote it out makes it more clear.  I'll try implementing it this way!

Comment: It works!  I ended up making ActiveList extend JPanel and be the "view" in your example, then created a JScrollPane and set the viewport in ChatGUI's constructor.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extending `JScrollPane` extend `JPanel` with proper layout. Add you `JRadioButtons` to the panel and place the panel in a `JScrollPane`.